# Не слушается иконка

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Левая иконка почему то не хочет подчиняться CSS-коду и должна выглядеть как две правые https://wampi.ru/image/Rc90C2O

```css
/* Features */

 .features {
  display: flex;
 }

 .features_item {
  flex: 1 1 0;

  padding-left: 90px;
  position: relative;
 }

 .features_icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: -26px;
  left: -49px;
  z-index: 1;
 }

 .features_title {
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #f6950a;

  text-transform: uppercase;
 }

 .features_text {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
 }
```

```html
<section class="section">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="section_header">
   <h2 class="section_title">Features of this site</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="features">

   <div class="features_item">
    <img class="features_icon"
    src="assets/image/features/vader.png">

    <div class="features_title">key characters</div>
    <div class="features_text">On our site you can read something interesting about key characters from different universes.</div>
   </div>

   <div class="features_item">
    <img class="features_icon"
    src="assets/image/features/boba.png">

    <div class="features_title">secondary characters</div>
    <div class="features_text">You also can find here information about secondary characters.</div>
   </div>

   <div class="features_item">
    <img class="features_icon"
    src="assets/image/features/storm.png">

    <div class="features_title">the characters of the third plan</div>
    <div class="features_text">Also we provide knowledges about guys of background.</div>
   </div>

   </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сместились иконки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135296/%d0%a1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8)